# How to change the facet scales using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis, facet

I'm trying to change the scale of some panels to get a better view. In `facet_grid` the `scales` are already `"free"`, however, I need a different scale for the row corresponding to the First Range. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
library (ggplot2)

Source <- c(rep("Water", 12), rep("Oil", 12))
Range <- rep((c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 8))),2)
Xaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)
Yaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)

DF <- data.frame(Source, Range, Xaxis, Yaxis)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Range~Source,
             scales = "free")
```

[image]

I would like the front row to look like this:

[image]

Comment: `facet_grid` cannot have free scales for both axes: see the linked question & answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use `facet_wrap()` instead of `facet_grid()`, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

Source <- c(rep("Water", 12), rep("Oil", 12))
Range <- rep((c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 8))),2)
Xaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)
Yaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)

DF <- data.frame(Source, Range, Xaxis, Yaxis)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(Range~Source,
             scales = "free")
```

[image: example_1.png]